# Why don't the C1 and C2 capacitors discharge?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-doubler

[image]

In the circuit, we know that when D1 is connected then the C1 capacitor is also in the circuit until it's fully charged. Why when D1 is disconnected and D2 and C2 are in the circuit, C1 can't discharge? What is the reason behind it? And so doesn't C2?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why shoud D1 discharge something when it is disconnected? Is this a translation problem?

Comment: If you're really asking why *C1* doesn't discharge (not D1), then the answer is that it *does* discharge through the load RL you drew in. You need to choose a value for C1 & C2 such that they don't discharge *much* before the next input AC cycle comes around.

Comment: @brhans sorry, I have had a typo. But the question is when a capacitor is charged it has to drain its voltage somewhere, but in this circuit, neither C1 nor C2 discharge when no current passes them, are you saying it's due to existence of Rl? Then why? What happens whe Rl is in the circuit?

Comment: @Jens sorry. Please read my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the circuit, we know that when D1 is connected then the C1 capacitor is also in the circuit until it's fully charged.

Terminology: D1 is permanently (always) connected. You mean "when D1 is forward biased (conducting)".

> Why when D1 is disconnected and D2 and C2 are in the circuit, C1 can't discharge?

The characteristic of a diode is to allow current to flow in one direction only - the direction of the arrow in its symbol.

The result is that C1 and C2 can't discharge back to the voltage source but they can discharge to the load, R<sub>L</sub>. The result of this will be to cause some ripple on the otherwise steady DC supply.

> What is the reason behind it?

[image]

You might find the non-return valve analogy useful on my page, [What is an LED](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/).

> And so doesn't C2?

D2 and C2 form in inverse of the D1 and C1 circuit. They generate a negative voltage relative to the C1 - C2 common node.

Comment: Thank you soooo much.